# dojo grid area get unreadable

Tags: dojo, grid

I have a dojo app making extensive use of dojo grid, after some take arround using the app all grids looks grey at all (no titles, no data, just all the area of the grids in grey).

Anyone have an idea of the possible causes for it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including all the necessary CSS?  The grid uses a few that aren't part of dijit's tundra.

```
    @import "/js/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css";
    @import "/js/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css";
    @import "/js/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
    @import "/js/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
```

If you have all of those, the next thing to check is that the grid starts off in a visible area.  I've run into a ton of trouble where the grid started off in a `display:hidden` div.

Hope this helps.  If not, let me know.